# Is compensation required for banned goods?

Tags: united-states

Suppose the government were to ban possession of a certain good, like food or drugs, and that this required holders of those goods to surrender the goods.

Would the government be required to compensate the (former) holders?

Comment: I'm sure the answer is no, but I have no background on why that is

Comment: Bans like this are generally on further production and sales, not private use, so it is likely you would be allowed to use up what you already have.  Or in the case of lawn darts, use them at your own discretion.

Comment: That makes sense—but there have definitely been bans on possession. Drugs are a notable example, as is real property when it is taken by the government.

Comment: But do you have a notable example of an FDA approved legal drug that was subsequently banned and those in possession were prohibited from using up what they already possessed?  And real property is generally only taken under "eminent domain", that isn't the same thing as a ban.  Not at all really, and generally land owners are compensated.  So when you say they have "famously banned" certain types of cheeses, do you have an example?

Comment: The FDA has banned cheese with live worms in it. Everything that the FDA has banned has at one point been legal. Illegal drugs used to be legal and aren't.

Comment: I am asking for a link to a credible article on such a ban.  because I don't think the government has any interest in going house to house confiscating cheese from "holders" of wormy cheese, so eat up.  Regarding drugs, I'm again looking for a specific example where gov banned a medicine and insisted users surrender what they had.  Most bans I'm familiar with allow continued possession if you already have something, and I just don't think you've really thought this question through...

Comment: @MichaelHall just consider illegal drugs. At one point they were legal, now they're illegal.

Comment: Actually, it's going the other direction - Once illegal drugs are rapidly becoming decriminalized.  "*what test would be applied to determine if compensation would be owed?*" is actually a good question, @jen, why don't you ask that separately?

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer, but the answer is probably yes, under the Takings Clause.

Comment: Note, that in many historical cases compensation was made into the law which banned possession in order for that ban to be better accepted by the population and to reduce opposition. Historically, it was often used in many countries when serfdom was abolished, or slavery was banned. The landowners were compensated by the state. Why? Because otherwise the change would not have gathered enough support, especially in a time where landowners had the biggest political power. It's like "ok, we surrender our privileges, but we want something in return, otherwise we will oppose the new law".

Comment: Gun buyback programs in several countries after a period of civil wars or anarchy are also a good example. When the civil war was ongoing many private individuals needed weapons and even organized themselves into militias to defend themselves from bandits, terrorists, raiders, etc. After a stable government is established, the number of weapons has to be reduced. But if guns are just confiscated outright, this would reduce the support of the government, people might hide them en masse. But a buyback program can incentivize people to comply.

Comment: There is [Executive Order 6102](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executive_Order_6102) which ordered that U.S. citizens could no longer hold an amount of gold over a $100 (circa 1933). The gold was exchanged for currency at $20.67 per troy ounce. There were similar laws passed in other countries, all with currency exchange.

Answer (score 7):

The prohibition against *casu marzu* and similar cheeses is not in terms of possession, it is in terms of manufacture and import. There is no law requiring owners of the cheese in the US to surrender their cheese, however if you buy some in Sardinia and attempt to bring it back (and get caught), they can legally confiscate it. There is no case where said cheese imported legally into the US was later confiscated from its owner. Similarly, the import and sale of African elephant ivory is illegal, but possession is legal. Even sale is legal under restricted circumstances. Again, there is no confiscation provision.

Possession of a machine gun is banned by [26 USC 5861](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/5861), under certain conditions, namely

> (b)to receive or possess a firearm transferred to him in violation of
> the provisions of this chapter; or (c) to receive or possess a firearm
> made in violation of the provisions of this chapter; or (d) to receive
> or possess a firearm which is not registered to him in the National
> Firearms Registration and Transfer Record

There are a few exemptions (for example, the Army is allowed to possess machine guns). There is a requirement for paying taxes and getting a license, which requires approval of the Attorney General. As you can see from the [original law](https://govtrackus.s3.amazonaws.com/legislink/pdf/stat/48/STATUTE-48-Pg1236.pdf), the specifically-prohibited weapons such as the machine gun had to be registered even if there was no sale / transfer – this is a tax power (it doesn't constitute confiscation). People who owned machine guns before the NFA was enacted could continue to possess their property, as long as they pay the tax and get a license.

Various chemical and herbal substances are outlawed under Title 21 ch. 13, the law regarding [simple possession](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/21/844) does in fact say that

> It shall be unlawful for any person knowingly or intentionally to
> possess a controlled substance unless such substance was obtained
> directly, or pursuant to a valid prescription or order, from a
> practitioner, while acting in the course of his professional practice,
> or except as otherwise authorized by this subchapter or subchapter II

so a person who owned a bag of pot when the law was passed would then be in violation of the law, unless there is an exception articulated elsewhere in that chapter. Under those circumstances, the original owner of the ancient pot would be entitled to compensation for the property that was taken by by law.

Comment: "Under those circumstances, the original owner of the ancient pot would be entitled to compensation for the property that was taken by by law."

Is the government **required** to compensate owners of pot? Or could they just pass a law saying "give us your pot, it's illegal to have now" without compensation?